# In Java, can a TypeVariable be converted to a Class object?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm trying to implement this method:

```
public static <T> T[] convertListToArray(List<T> toConvert) { ... }
```

But I have been unable to convert the `List<T>` object into a `Class<T>` object which I need to instantiate the array.  I'm not sure if this is even possible due to "Type Erasure", but thought I would try.  Here is how far I got before getting stuck:

```
public static <T> T[] convertListToArray(List<T> toConvert) throws Exception {
  Class<?> curClass = Class.forName("thispackage.ListUtils");
  Method method = curClass.getDeclaredMethod("convertListToArray", List.class);
  Type[] typeArray = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
  ParameterizedType listType = (ParameterizedType)typeArray[0];
  Type[] genericTypes = listType.getActualTypeArguments();
  TypeVariable genericType = (TypeVariable)genericTypes[0];
  //Got stuck here, can a "TypeVariable" be converted to a "Class<?>"?

  String genericName = genericType.getTypeName();
  System.out.println(genericName); //Prints "T"
  //this of course doesn't work, throws ClassNotFoundException at runtime
  Class<?> arrayClass = Class.forName(genericName);

  int size = toConvert.size();
  T[] retArray = (T[])Array.newInstance(arrayClass, size);
  return toConvert.toArray(retArray); 
}
```

So, is it possible to convert a `TypeVariable` into a `Class<?>`?

Comment: No, but you can declare a second parameter of type `Class<T>` and pass an appropriate argument for it.

Comment: Just in case, you know Collection already has such a method, right? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T[]%29

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis True, but then this method is about the same as List.toArray (which I was trying to simplify), so I would probably just abandon the idea.

Comment: @JBNizet, yes, at the bottom you can see I'm using toArray, the goal was not not have to provide the array as a parameter.

Comment: @overcast75 if that was possible, I bet Collection would have such a method...

Comment: What simplification did you mean to make?

Comment: @JBNizet In the past I have found there was usually a way (though often convoluted), but that doesn't appear to be the case this time.  The only thing I have come up with is to guess at the T type by checking the class of the members of the list (technically I would have to check all of them and if they differ, look for superclasses and interfaces), but that doesn't work if the list is empty.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis not having to pass in any information about the resulting array, just pass in the List and get back the T[].

Comment: There is a hack. Use `Array.newInstance(list.get(0).getClass(), list.size())`. This creates an array of the class of the first item in the list. This will cause an `ArrayStoreException` if the other items don't have the same class, so it's not a good idea.

Comment: I see. Then @JBNizet's comment is what you should concentrate on. _Collection would have such a method_.

Comment: @pbabcdefp, I tried the hack but didn't like that drawbacks I mention above (especially that it breaks with empty lists)

Comment: There's no other way. What you are trying to do is impossible. Arrays enforce the type at runtime, whereas a `List<T>` doesn't even know `T` at runtime (it's just a `List`).

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to prior to posting, but wanted to make sure I just hadn't missed something.  Getting a generics class type at runtime seems like something that should be possible.

Answer (score -1):

Key is to figuring out what is the type of `T`, Despite of real usage of this method, simply this would work.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] convertListToArray(List<T> toConvert) throws Exception {
        if (!toConvert.isEmpty()) {
            Class<?> aClass = toConvert.get(0).getClass();
            T[] t = (T[]) Array.newInstance(aClass, toConvert.size());
            return toConvert.toArray(t);
        }
        return (T[]) toConvert.toArray();
    }
```